# error when importing json file to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, import

When I imported a json file into mongodb, I got an error "Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'F' looking for beginning of value". I checked the content of the json file and found mongodb did not accept "False, True, None, none" values when importing.

For example, if a json is
{
  'has_issues': True,
  'has_projects': True,
  'has_downloads': False,
  'has_wiki': None
}, the True, False, None need to be replaced when successfully importing.

Do anyone know why such a situation happens? Many thanks.

Is there a way in mongodb to automatically converting non-json values (e.g. True, False, None, none) to json values (e.g., true, false, null)?

Answer (score 1):

False, True, None or none are not JSON values.
http://www.json.org/json-fr.html

false, true and null are JSON values.

Comment: Thanks, I notice that. So the next question is if there exists a way in mongodb for automatically converting non-json values to json values when data importing.

Comment: AFAIK, not with MongoDB, you need to develop your own script.